# SQL: Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax

Ok, I've been staring at this for too long and I can't figure it out. How long? ***Too long.*** What is the cause of the error? It points to the `THEN` statement.

```
DECLARE @lp varchar(30) = '307856874'
DECLARE @item varchar(30) = '%'
DECLARE @loc varchar(8) = '%'
DECLARE @lot varchar(20) = '%'
DECLARE @trans_type varchar(20) = '%'
DECLARE @trans_date datetime = NULL;
DECLARE @desc varchar(20) = '%'
DECLARE @whse varchar(20) = '%'
DECLARE @qty decimal = NULL;


SELECT

    t.lp_num,
    t.item,
    t.loc,
    t.lot,
    t.trans_type,
    t.trans_date,
    t.description,
    t.whse,
    t.qty,
    t.u_m,
    t.emp_num,
    t.ref_num,
    t.ref_line_suf,
    t.createdate,
    t.FGLotCode,
    t.Uf_Shift,
    t.Uf_shift_start_date,
    t.Uf_TruckID,
    t.Uf_EdiExtracted


FROM

    ISW_LPTrans AS t

WHERE

    LTRIM(RTRIM((t.lp_num))) LIKE @lp AND
    t.item LIKE @item AND
    t.loc LIKE @loc AND
    t.lot LIKE @lot AND
    t.trans_type LIKE @trans_type AND
    (@trans_date IS NULL OR t.trans_date = @trans_date) AND 
    t.description LIKE @desc AND
    t.whse LIKE @whse AND
    (CASE 
        WHEN (@qty IS NULL)
        THEN (t.qty = 112) 
        ELSE (t.qty = @qty)
    END)
```

Comment: show all the code ..

Comment: you are comparing with `null`. change `@qty = NULL` to `@qty IS NULL`.

Comment: @vkp made the change, but still getting the same error.

Comment: The `case` expression returns a scalar value. You can't assign/compare values to variables/columns in `THEN`, which is what you are trying to do, comparing `t.qty`.

Comment: Added full code for complete clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign in the case statement.

```
t.qty = CASE 
           WHEN (@qty IS NULL) THEN 112
           ELSE @qty)
        END
```

I recommend to change the end for clarity:

```
t.qty=ISNULL(@qty,112)
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. I'll accept this answer as correct in 9 minutes, when it lets me do so.

Comment: even better is COALESCE(@qty,112) since that will work on all platforms and is a SQL standard.